# Implicit rules messing up Makefile for compiling CUDA sources (.cu -> .cu.o)

Tags: makefile, dependencies, circular-dependency

I have a simple Makefile for building a project with several C++ sources/targets and several CUDA sources/targets. Recently I needed to add a feature flag for all targets and continually test the behavior between the original targets (without the feature flag) and the new targets (with the feature flag) while developing the feature. So I decided that I will keep the same source files, but add more targets to the Makefile which will have different compile flags. This worked quite well for the C++ part, but I noticed a strange behavior for the CUDA part, which I will try to outline below in a simplified Makefile:

```
$(shell touch foo.cu)

GROUP1_SOURCES=$(wildcard *.cu)
GROUP1_TARGETS=$(GROUP1_SOURCES:%.cu=%)
GROUP2_SOURCES=$(wildcard *.cu)
GROUP2_TARGETS=$(GROUP2_SOURCES:%.cu=%_grp2)

.PHONY: all clean
all: $(GROUP1_TARGETS) $(GROUP2_TARGETS)
group1: $(GROUP1_TARGETS)
group2: $(GROUP2_TARGETS)

clean:
    $(RM) foo*

$(GROUP1_TARGETS): % : %.cu.o
    touch $@

$(GROUP1_SOURCES:%.cu=%.cu.o): %.cu.o : %.cu
    $(info Rule 1: $@)
    touch $@

$(GROUP2_TARGETS): % : %.cu.o
    touch $@

$(GROUP2_SOURCES:%.cu=%_grp2.cu.o): %_grp2.cu.o : %.cu
    $(info Rule 2: $@)
    touch $@
```

Of course in the real world I run the compiler instead of `touch`, but compilation is not the problem, so I simplified so there is no need to create real source files.

`GROUP1` denotes the "original" sources where the chain should be `foo.cu -> foo.cu.o -> foo`. The object file has extension `.cu.o`, because there might be `foo.cpp` which is compiled into `foo.o`. This might be part of the problem, because somehow this creates a circular dependency which is dropped by make, but otherwise making `group1` seems to work fine:

```
$ make group1
make: Circular foo.cu <- foo.cu.o dependency dropped.
Rule 1
touch foo.cu.o
touch foo
```

`GROUP2` contains targets with a different features which are specified by different compile flags (not visible in this example). They are created from the same sources, so I added the `_grp2` suffix to the target and object files. Now this leads to some weird/interesting behavior, because running `make group2` multiple times leads to different behavior:

```
$ make clean
rm -f foo*
$ make group2
make: Nothing to be done for 'group2'.
$ make group2
make: Circular foo.cu.o <- foo.cu dependency dropped.
Rule 1
touch foo.cu.o
cc   foo.cu.o   -o foo.cu
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.1.0/../../../../lib/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [<builtin>: foo.cu] Error 1
$ make group2
make: Nothing to be done for 'group2'.
$ make group2
make: Circular foo.cu.o <- foo.cu dependency dropped.
Rule 2
touch foo_grp2.cu.o
touch foo_grp2
```

1. At first invokation I got an error because the file `foo.cu` did not exist (this is expected and not the issue).
2. Then `make` decided to run the rule for `GROUP1_SOURCES` instead of `GROUP2_SOURCES` (it printed `Rule 1`). This is a problem - why does it happen?
3. Then `make` thought "Nothing to be done for 'group'." This is a problem, but probably just a consequence of the previous issue.
4. Finally, the fourth (and each next) invokation triggers the rule for `GROUP2_SOURCES` as expected.

I assume this has something to do with some implicit rules messing with my rules, because there is no circular dependency in my Makefile and `make` even runs the compiler after `Rule 1` in the 2. step. Can you explain what is happening?

Comment: There are varied methods to yield 2+ custom builds from the same source. One of the simpler methods directs obj files to subdirs and each group can be built with custom features. Let me know if that's OK for your project and I'll post an example Makefile.

Comment: Hmm, I guess that would be the easiest solution. If you can link to some examples and briefly describe other alternatives, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

```
#
# example Makefile based on OP version
# build 2 sets of obj with- or without feature flags
#

# $(shell touch foo.cu)

# regular, feature
TARGET_REG := reg-name
TARGET_FTR := ftr-name

DIR_REG := objreg
DIR_FTR := objftr
# $(shell mkdir -p $(DIR_REG) $(DIR_FTR)

CU_SRC := $(wildcard *.cu)
CU_OBJ := $(CU_SRC:%.cu=%-cu.o)
# $(info CU_SRC "$(CU_SRC)")
# $(info CU_OBJ "$(CU_OBJ)")

OBJ_REG := $(addprefix $(DIR_REG)/, $(CU_OBJ))
OBJ_FTR := $(addprefix $(DIR_FTR)/, $(CU_OBJ))
# $(info OBJ_REG "$(OBJ_REG)")
# $(info OBJ_FTR "$(OBJ_FTR)")

# added feature flags:
FTR_FLAGS := -abc

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(TARGET_REG) $(TARGET_FTR)

$(TARGET_REG): $(OBJ_REG)
    @echo -e "    link $@, OBJ $^\n"

$(TARGET_FTR): $(OBJ_FTR)
    @echo -e "    link $@, OBJ $^\n"

clean:
    $(RM) foo* $(OBJ_REG) $(OBJ_FTR)

$(OBJ_FTR): CU_STUFF += $(FTR_FLAGS)

$(DIR_REG)/%-cu.o: %.cu
    @echo build $< to $@, CU_STUFF \"$(CU_STUFF)\"

$(DIR_FTR)/%-cu.o: %.cu
    @echo build $< to $@, CU_STUFF \"$(CU_STUFF)\"
```